# How to get the values in DataFrame with the correct DataType?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I tried to get some values in a `DataFrame`, like:

```
df.select("date").head().get(0) // type: Any
```

The result type is `Any`, which is not expected.
Since a `dataframe` contains the `schema` of the data, it should know the `DataType` for each `column`, so when i try to get a value using `get(0)`, it should return the value with the correct type. However, it does not.

Instead, I need to specify which `DataType` i want using `getDate(0)`, which seems weird, inconvenient, and makes me mad.

When I have specified the `schema` with the correct `DataTypes` for each `column` when i created the `Dataframe`, I don't want to use different `getXXX()' for different`column`s.

Are there some convenient ways that I can get the values with their own correct types? That is to say, how can I get the values with the correct `DataType` specified in the `schema`?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala is a statically typed language. so the `get` method defined on the Row can only return values with a single type because the return type of the get method is `Any`. It cannot return `Int` for one call and a `String` for another.

you should be calling the `getInt`, `getDate` and other get methods provided for each type. Or the `getAs` [method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@getAs[T](fieldName:String):T) in which you can pass the type as a parameter (for example `row.getAs[Int](0)`).

As mentioned in the comments other options are

- use Dataset instead of a DataFrame.
- use Spark SQL

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is that, if i have many columns, I dont want to  call different functions to get the value of different columns. So far, as I know, one solution is that convert the dataframe to dataset using `case class`. But another problem is that, since my input data set varies, I cant hard code an `case class` for each data set. So I am confused now.

Comment: using Dataset is not a bad idea.. apart from Dataset and the Dataframe option there isnt much we could do.

Comment: Is 'case class' the only way that convert DataFrame to DataSet? And If I have an array with the column types, how can i do the convert using the array?

Comment: no. you can use Tuples instead of case classes if you want. But case classes are recommended over Tuples espcially when the number of fields is very large. BTW can you accept one of the posted answer by clicking the Tick mark in the answer?

Comment: mark is done. But i have yet questions... Whether using tuple or case class, I have to declare them "hard coded". While my input data sets are so different, that I can't hard code them in the program. What I prefer is that if I have an array with the column types, can I declare the tuple or case class dynamically and then use them to convert?

Comment: creating tuples dynamically is most likely not possible. Tuples are not collections.. you cannot append or change it like you would do to a list.. I would suggest to just create the case classes.. it would worth the effort or else use DataFrames and handle types manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the generic `getAs` method as `getAs[Int](columnIndex)`, `getAs[String](columnIndex)` or use specific methods like `getInt(columnIndex)`, `getString(columnIndex)`.

Link to the [Scaladoc for org.apache.spark.sql.Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row).