# How do I get the value without the square brackets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, qubole

I have created a dataframe using Scala and Spark SQL. I wanted the first value from the table but I am getting it inside of square brackets []. Can I just get the value without the brackets?

**Code:**

```
val sigh = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT DISTINCT accountId FROM table""")
sigh.show()
sigh.select("accountId").first()
```

**Results:**

```
sigh: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [accountId: string]
+----------+
| accountId|
+----------+
|1370244502|
+----------+
res54: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [1370244502]
```

**Expected Results**

```
sigh: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [accountId: string]
+----------+
| accountId|
+----------+
|1370244502|
+----------+
res54: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = 1370244502
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first` returns a Row object, and you can use `getString` method to extract elements from the row as string:

```
sigh.select("accountId").first.getString(0)
```

Comment: Looks more or less like duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138868/2707792).